# Totem: How to change playlist contents' name?

Tags: totem, internet-radio, playlists

I added several online radio feeds to Totem playlist, but what is displayed on the sidebar are the names of the songs that were playing when it was added to the playlist instead of the radio's name.

For example, the radio "Classical Guitar" shows instead "Debussy - Golliwog's Cakewalk" and the Bossa Nova channel shows as "Nancy Wilson - How insensitive".

Please advise me on how to change their names and in what folder is this info stored?

Thanks a bunch!!

[image: Totem image]